# Возможно ли сделать выборку из базы одной переменной?

Tags: php, mysqli

Расширение **mysqli** .

Чтобы получать данные из БД мне нужно написать следующий код:

```
$sql_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$user_id' AND `solt` = '$solt'");
$sql_user = $sql_user->fetch_assoc();
```

То есть тут нужно перезаписать переменную **sql_user**

Можно добиться такого же результата без перезаписи?

Comment: ну напишите так
    $results = $sql_user->fetch_assoc();

Comment: @sterx и? вопрос то в другом. тут не суть что одно и тоже название переменной.

Comment: Ну а что собсно мешает сделать ``$sql_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$user_id' AND `solt` = '$solt'")->fetch_assoc();``?

Comment: @Akina пробовал. выдает ошибку

Comment: вместо `*` укажите в запросе конкретное выбираемое поле и пользуйтесь `->fetch_row()[0]`

Comment: Слова "выдаёт ошибку" оставьте дилетантам. У ошибки всегда есть код и сообщение, и скрывать их - неразумно.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$user_id' AND `solt` = '$solt'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    // если нужно вернуть только одну запись используйте метод fetch_row и укажите LIMIT 1
    $sql_user = $result->fetch_row();

    // если нужно вернуть все записи используйте метод fetch_assoc и цикл while
    while($sql_user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ...
    }

    $result->free();
}
```